# JS Bitwise - what are the rules of Math.random() * 2 being interpreted as 0 and 1 for purposes of bitwise Or (|) operation?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

Why learning about bind() method on http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/, I have come across an interesting calculation which looks like this:

```
var randomNum = ((Math.random () * 2 | 0) + 1) - 1;
```

Trying to understand what | sign does, I came across JavaScript Bitwise operators (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp).

And I got to know that `(Math.random () * 2 | 0)` is a bitwise OR operation.

I grasped that `Math.random() * 2` sometimes gives value of 0 or 1 in terms of bitwise values (for example, 0.06218657045669751 is interpreted as 1). I wrote a function to check, in which situations the result of `Math.random() * 2` calculation is treated as 0 and in which it is treated as 1:

```
function showNumber() {
  console.log(Math.random() * 2);

  return Math.random() * 2 | 0;
}
showNumber();
```

The results did not give me any answer to my questions.
Because if `Math.random() * 2` gives 1.5337258727722651 it can as well be interpreted as 1 and 0.

Is this interpretation random by rule or is there any logic behind?

Comment: If `Math.random()` returns `1.5337258727722651` and you bitwise-OR that with `0`, the result will **always** be `1`.  The number is truncated to a 32-bit integer by the `|` operator.

Comment: Your `showNumber` function will print one number but likely return another since you call `Math.random()` twice. So there isn't any relation between the printed number and the number the function returns.

Comment: `number | 0` is a bad way of writing `Math.floor(number)`. Also the `+1` and `-1` is useless.

Comment: @EmilH good point. Can I assume then that if I have 0.06218657045669751 as a result of Math.random() * 2 calculation, it will then be interpreted as 0, and if I have 1.5337258727722651, it will be interpreted as 1?

Comment: @RolandStarke what you are saying makes perfect sense to me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, OR'ing with false (0) doesn't do anything: `x or false` is equivalent to `x`. The same goes for bitwise OR with the number 0. The `x | 0` construction is just a JavaScript idiom for turning a floating-point number into an integer (truncating).

Because `Math.random() * 2` is a number between 0.0 (inclusive) and 2.0 (exclusive), rounding down in this way gives a 50/50 chance of being either 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

@Thomas already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48265911/3978539) the question of why this returns 0 or 1. However, I would like to emphasise the difference between `Math.floor` and `| 0` (as mentioned in the comments).

In most cases, these would indeed provide the same result and in most cases, `Math.floor` would be easier to read and understand, especially for beginners.

If your input is from a user or a database, you can't be sure the input is really a number. `Math.floor` correctly handles string values, but does have a few weird quirks for other kinds of values.

For example: `Math.floor(null)` returns `0`, while `Math.floor(undefined)` returns `NaN`. Using the bitwise operator, `0` would be returned in both cases.

Taking it a step further would be to have an object as input. `Math.floor({})` returns `NaN` while `a={}; a | 0` still returns `0` and `{} | 0` would actually throw a SyntaxError.

A more credible example would be to pass `NaN` as input. `Math.floor` would return `NaN` and the bitwise operator would return `0`.

So in short, the bitwise operator always returns a valid 32-bit integer, while `Math.floor` may also return `NaN`.

Comment: I'm reminded of [Unicode, Dammit](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit) from BeautifulSoup. Similarly, `| 0` is Integer, Dammit.

Comment: @Stephan Bijzitter, very useful information. Thank you!